# Formating problem - json file to html page

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to get the information in their proper place in the form above. 
The data is from a json file 
I am just trying to display it cleanly on the html page with the number fields. 
Can someone take a look at my code and tell me which part in js that I need to change or add?
So for instance 
Under menu there is a number field.  I want to display the Slice of Pizza $2 to the left of this.
How would I go about that?  If someone can show me one example I would greatly appreciate it.

```
   <body>
   <div id="order"></div>
   <div id="menuOutput">
   <h1 class="menu">Menu</h1>
    <div class="grid">
    <div class="two">
      <h2></h2>
      <input type="number" id="qty_slice of pizza">
      <h2>Toppings</h2>
      <p class="titles"></p> <input type="number" id="qty_pepperoni">
      <p class="titles"></p> <input type="number" id="qty_meatballs">
      <p class="titles"></p> <input type="number" id="qty_mushrooms">
      <p class="titles"></p> <input type="number" id="qty_olives">
    </div>

    <div class="one">
      <h2>Sides</h2>
      <p class="titles"></p> <input type="number" id="qty_potato salad">
      <p class="titles"></p> <input type="number" id="qty_hummus">
      <p class="titles"></p> <input type="number" id="qty_caesar salad">
      <p class="titles"></p> <input type="number" id="qty_garden salad">
    </div>

    <div class="three">
        <h2></h2>
        <div>

          <p class="titles"></p> <input type="number" id="qty_small">
          <p class="titles"></p> <input type="number" id="qty_medium">
          <p class="titles"></p> <input type="number" id="qty_large">
        </div><hr>
      <p class="titles"></p> <input type="number" id="qty_juice">
      <p class="titles"></p> <input type="number" id="qty_water">

    </div>
 </div><br>
 </div>
 <div class="button">
  <button type class="button" id="submitOrder" onclick="retrieveOrder()">Review Order</button>
 </div>
 <div id="order"></div>
 <script src="./run.js"></script>
 </body>
 </html>

//get menu from api
var getJSON = function(url, callback) {
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('get', url, true);
xhr.responseType = 'json';
xhr.onload = function() {
  var status = xhr.status;
  if (status == 200) {
    callback(null, xhr.response);
  } else {
    callback(status);
  }
};
xhr.send();
};

/*
{
"menu": {
"slice of pizza": "2.00",
qty_slice of pizza
"toppings": {
  "pepperoni": ".25",
  "meatballs": ".35",
  "mushrooms": ".40",
  "olives": ".20"
 },
 "sides": {
  "potato salad": "1.25",
  "hummus": "2.50",
  "caesar salad": "3.50",
  "garden salad": "2.25"
  },
  "drinks": {
  "soda": {
    "small": "1.95",
    "medium": "2.20",
    "large": "2.50"
  },
  "juice": "2.00",
  "water": "1.25"
  }
  }
  }
  */

  const fNum = str => {
  str = str.trim()
  return str && !isNaN(str) ? "$" + Number(str).toFixed(2) : str;
  };


  getJSON('https://mm214.com/menu.php', function(err, data) {
  // console.log(data)
  if (err != null) {
  alert('Something went wrong: ' + err);
  } else {
  const container = document.getElementById("menuOutput");
  const menu = data.menu;
  Object.keys(menu).forEach(key => {
  const div = document.createElement("div");
  const header = document.createElement("h2");
  header.textContent = key
  div.appendChild(header)
  const sub = menu[key];
  if (typeof sub === 'object') {
    Object.keys(sub).forEach(subKey => {
      const subDiv = document.createElement("div")
      const subHeader = document.createElement("h3")
      subHeader.textContent = subKey;
      subDiv.appendChild(subHeader)
      const subsub = sub[subKey];
      if (typeof subsub === 'object') {
        Object.keys(subsub).forEach(subsubKey => {
          const p = document.createElement("p")
          p.textContent = subsubKey + ": " + fNum(subsub[subsubKey]);
          subDiv.appendChild(p)
        });
      } else {
        subHeader.appendChild(document.createTextNode(": " + fNum(subsub)))
      }

      div.appendChild(subDiv)
    })
  } else {
    header.appendChild(document.createTextNode(": " + fNum(sub)))
  }

  container.appendChild(div)
  })
  }
  //closes outer for loop
  });
 //localStorage only stores strings! Stringify turns objects into strings!
 //parse converts JSON strings to objects that can be looped around

 document.getElementById("menuOutput").innerHTML = content;
 localStorage.setItem('order',JSON.stringify(data));


 var order = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('order'));
 console.log(typeof(order));
 for (a in order){
 console.log(a + ':' + order[a]);
 }

 ;


 function storeOrder(){
 var pizzaqty = document.getElementById('qty_slice of pizza').value;
 localStorage.setItem('pizza',pizzaqty);
 var price  = pizzaqty * 2;


 }


 function retrieveOrder(){
 var pizzaordered = localStorage.getItem('pizza');


 }

 //output html
 //
 //document.getElementById("menuOutput").innerHTML = "Here is the menu: <br>" + data.menu;
 //why in't this working?

 //style menu for ordering
 //save order as json string
 //save in local storage
 //your order button

 //onclick: show order  
 document.getElementById('order').innerHTML = localStorage.getItem('order1');


@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2? 
family=Bangers&family=Bree+Serif&family=Chelsea+Market&family=Oswald:wght@300&display=swap');

.grid {
display: grid;
grid-template-areas:
    "one two three"
    "one two three"
    "one two three";
grid-template-columns: 1fr 2fr 1fr;
grid-template-rows: repeat(3, 165px);
 }

.title {
font-family: 'Chelsea Market', cursive;
font-size: 30px;
text-align: center;
color: teal;
}

input[type="number"] {
width: 40px;
}

.menu {
text-align: center;
}

.button {
text-align: center;
font-family: 'Bangers', cursive;
font-size: 25px;
}

.titles {
font-family: 'Bree Serif', serif;
}

.pizza {
text-align: center;
color: tomato;
background-color: teal;
}

.one {
grid-area: one;
background-color: #008c45;
text-align: center;
}


.two {
text-align: center;
grid-area: two;
background-color: #f4f5f0;
color: black;
}

.three {
grid-area: three;
text-align: center;
background-color: #cd212a;
}

h2, h3 {
font-size: 30px;
font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
text-align: center;
text-transform: capitalize;
}
```

Comment: where is the form tag ? why don't you use names and  FormData() as recomanded ?

Comment: `id="qty_slice of pizza"` is invalid...

Comment: No form tag...can you show me an example of a better solution to get what I am looking for?

Comment: fomData documentation have sample code...  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/FormData

Comment: thats cool, but how would I add an entire json file into these from an entire json file?  Would I have to run a for loop and inner for loop?

Comment: Men, It's more than 250 lines of code to read! what you are asking for is to spend 1 hour to read and understand what you are doing, and 1 hour more to answer ... if you expect to get an answer, you should do a synthetic, minimal and reproducible example of what you are looking for. anyway that's part of SO recommendations you're supposed to know  https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example